# R filter per group for first and last timepoints only

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, group-by

I have a dataset with column names ID, date, coverage. Each ID has a different number of dates. Coverage is an integer 0-3. I want to filter this dataset so that coverage==3 for the earliest and last time point only.
Example input:

```
ID date coverage
001 2012-12-24 2
001 2013-12-04 3
001 2014-12-14 1
001 2015-12-02 3
001 2016-12-02 0
002 2012-01-15 3
002 2013-11-15 1
002 2014-11-15 3
003 2019-01-15 1
003 2020-11-15 1
003 2021-11-15 3
```

Example output:

```
ID date coverage
001 2013-12-04 3
001 2014-12-14 1
001 2015-12-02 3
002 2012-01-15 3
002 2013-11-15 1
002 2014-11-15 3
003 2021-11-15 3
```

Answer (score 0):

We `arrange` the 'ID', 'date', grouped by 'ID', `slice` the rows from the first coverage of 3 value to the `last`.  Note that if there are no 3 values in coverage, we may need a condition to either drop the IDs by having an `if/else` condition with `else` returning `NULL` (or if we want the full data rows for those IDs, use `row_number()`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   arrange(ID, date) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   slice(if(3 %in% coverage) 
      match(3, coverage):last(which(coverage == 3)) else NULL)  %>%
   # if we want to keep the full rows
   #  slice(if(3 %in% coverage) 
   #    match(3, coverage):last(which(coverage == 3)) else row_number())  %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 × 3
     ID date       coverage
  <int> <date>        <int>
1     1 2013-12-04        3
2     1 2014-12-14        1
3     1 2015-12-02        3
4     2 2012-01-15        3
5     2 2013-11-15        1
6     2 2014-11-15        3
7     3 2021-11-15        3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), date = structure(c(15698, 16043, 16418, 16771, 17137, 15354, 
16024, 16389, 17911, 18581, 18946), class = "Date"), coverage = c(2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: when I try this, I get the following error: Error in match(3, coverage):last(which(coverage == 3)) : NA/NaN argument

Comment: @alison123456 probably in some  IDs, you may not have any `3` value?  Do you have those cases?  If that is the case, do you want to remove those IDs in the output

Comment: @alison123456 I updated the post.  IN case you want to drop, use the updated code (or if we want to keep full rows for that ID, replace with the code in the commented section)